# I can't seem to make my keyboardWillShow work?

Tags: ios, swift

My code does not show any errors but when I start the simulator the app crashes. I can't seem to find the problem, but it started crashing when I implemented ''keyboardWillShow''.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(with:)),
        name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
        object: nil)

}

// Mark: Actions

@objc func keyboardWillShow(with notification: Notification) {
    let key = "UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey"
    guard let keyboardFrame = notification.userInfo?[key] as? NSValue else { return }
    let keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue.height

    buttomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the name is wrong of your observer adding. Try:         NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil) and declare your selector func as follow: @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification)

Comment: @Klinki I tried the code but then I get the error: Type 'NSNotification.Name' has no member 'UIResponder'.

Comment: @JohnDoe which swift version do you use? Is your "buttomConstraint" connected? Maybe this is nil. Use Breakpoints to check this.

Comment: Maybe your constraint outlet isn't set?

Comment: @Klinki I'm using ver 4.2.1 and I've connected my buttomConstraint

Comment: it seems like I found the problem, code is fine but I get 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier reuseIdentifier - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

Comment: problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was stupid enough to forget to change my ''reuseIdentifier''.
The code was fine from the start! Thanks for all the quick answers and help :D

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes in Swift 4.2. I am not sure but try the following in your "keyboardWillShow" - func:

```
let frameEndUserInfoKey = UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey
if let kbFrame = notification.userInfo?[frameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect {
    let keyboardHeight = kbFrame.size.height
    buttomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```